# Sharepoint group is visible in people picker even after deleting from User Profile

Tags: user-profile, people-picker

I need to add an ID to a Sharepoint 2010 site. The id which is shown in the people picker search of the site is not configured correctly. Now, the ID is deleted from the User profile service corresponding to the application. But still the id is showing up in people picker of the site. I am not sure if it picking from any cache. I have checked in the profile database as well, the ID doesnt exist.

Please help me on how to find from where the profile is getting populated and how to delete the same.

Answer (score 3):

UPSA isn't directly involved in the People Picker, so removing the group from the UPSA won't do anything for you. This is often a point of confusion for many.

Instead, you have to remove it from the Site Collection itself. You can navigate to `https://siteUrl/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0` and remove the group from there.

Comment: The id seems to be having permission on the site through NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users. Can you please help me with how to remove the ID further? When the ID is searched through PP it is not reflecting all the properties of the profile from AD. Hence unable to configure for email alerts in the site. Is there any way to delete or readd or edit it from site perspective? The ID is showing up as expected on other applications in the same farm

Comment: Did you remove Authenticated Users (and/or 'Everyone')? That is any user who can authenticate to the domain.

Comment: No I havent removed it. I am not supposed to do it.

Comment: SharePoint doesn't have an explicit deny right. The only way you can deny a user access while having Auth Users on a Site Collection is to do it at the Web Application User Policy level. This will prevent those users who are members of the group from accessing *any* Site Collection within that Web Application.

Comment: Okay thanks for that info. Now the ID is having email address configured in the AD, but email id column is empty when I searched through PP. So I thought to delete and re-add if there is any possibility. Can you help me if there is any way to resolve this?

Comment: This seems to be off topic for this particular question. Can you start a new question instead?

Comment: Yup.. I have posted it as a different question